# Set the supported lowest supported Android version in a Nativescript app.

Tags: android, google-play, nativescript

I've deployed a Nativescript app to Google Play for my beta testers to use. My app is only intended to support Android version 4.4 and above. So I thought setting this in the AndroidManifest would get the job done.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>
```

Yet once deployed the Play store is still saying that those running Android versions lower than 4.4 can still download the app. What else do I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: Hey Stavros - I have logged this behaviour ni this thread https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/575 where you can track for possible solutions for this issue

Comment: @user1506104 Yes, I do have an app.gradle file.

Comment: Android Studio uses the values of minSdk and targetSdk set in app.gradle.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not building this app with Android Studio :(

Comment: then, make sure that what you have in gradle is the same as what you have in manifest to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the thread below where a solution is shown on how to modify your minimum SDK version with app.gradle

https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/575#issuecomment-251584253

Basically as Plamen5kov has shown, you have to do the following:

> what you can do is go to app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle and
>   change the default configuration to meet your requirements.

```
 android {     
     defaultConfig {  
         minSdkVersion 19 ....
```

> Gradle overrides the AndroidManifest.xml that's why you need to change
>   the configuration in gradle, rather than in the manifest file.